# How to make a diagonal matrix from a vector

Tags: matrix, julia, diagonal

```
using LinearAlgebra;
        a = rand(4,1);
        B = diagm(a);
        C  = Diagonal(a);
```

The above code causes an error/(not intended)  in creating a diagonal matrix.

if `a = [1 2 3 4]`

I need a matrix like:

```
D = [1 0 0 0;0 2 0 0;0 0 3 0;0 0 0 4].
```

C = Diagonal(a) creates
C = [1]

B = diagm(a); gives an error message:

> Error messages: ERROR: MethodError: no method matching
> diagm(::Matrix{Float64})
>
> You might have used a 2d row vector where a 1d column vector was
> required. Note the difference between 1d column vector [1,2,3] and 2d
> row vector [1 2 3]. You can convert to a column vector with the vec()
> function. Closest candidates are:   diagm(::Pair{var"#s832",
> var"#s831"} where {var"#s832"<:Integer, var"#s831"<:(AbstractVector{T}
> where T)}...) at
> C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:279
> diagm(::Integer, ::Integer, ::Pair{var"#s832", var"#s831"} where
> {var"#s832"<:Integer, var"#s831"<:(AbstractVector{T} where T)}...) at
> C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:280
> diagm(::AbstractVector{T} where T) at
> C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:329
> ... Stacktrace:  [1] top-level scope    @ REPL[16]:1

Comment: The error message is actually quite good here, and exactly explains the problem and how to solve it: "You might have used a 2d row vector where a 1d column vector was required. Note the difference between 1d column vector [1,2,3] and 2d row vector [1 2 3]. You can convert to a column vector with the vec() function."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is your `a` is matrix.

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  # 4-element Vector{Int64}
C = Diagonal(a)
4×4 Diagonal{Int64, Vector{Int64}}:
 1  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  3  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  4
```

Or, to make a true diagonal matrix:

```
M = diagm(a)
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0  0  0
 0  2  0  0
 0  0  3  0
 0  0  0  4
```

Comment: Nice tutorial [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/551/julia/tutor/03-diag.html) explaining the various types of diagonal matrix in Julia.

Comment: Worth commenting is that the first option by @Bill is not materialized as a `Matrix` so linear algebra operations on it will be much  faster (as long a you stick to functions having specific implementation for the `Diagonal` argument)

Comment: @Bill, what is the best way to produce a normalized adjacency matrix in Julia?

Comment: @Vass I'm not sure. Is this related to this question or is it a different question?

Comment: @Bill, the diagonal is key in producing normalized adjacency matrices

Comment: @Vass I would consider asking a new question if you can't find an answer online. You can always reference this one.